"Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'." error while generating SHA Keys for my Flutter app
To open my android folder of my Flutter app, I ran this command:
cd android

Then, I ran this command:
./gradlew app:signingReport

But, I get this error:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'E:\Fluter\New folder\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\app_plugin_loader.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 64

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights."

How can I solve it?

You can generate a SHA key using the keytool.
Open the android folder using command:
cd android 

Run the following command to generate the SHA key:
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

The above command generates SHA key for debug app.  If you want to generate one for a release mode then:
keytool -list -v -keystore /PATH_TO_RELEASE_KEYSTORE -alias ALIAS_NAME -storepass KEYSTORE_PASSWORD -keypass KEYSTORE_PASSWORD

